# Will coefficient of performance rise in the future for heat pumps?

Tags: energy-efficiency, heat-pump

I can see there are heat pumps with x > 4.1 [SCOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance), which is great!

**Q:** But will this get better in the future? Ex. in 10 years? New type of heat-pumps?

Or are there any psyhical limitations, that will only provide SCOP between around 4-5-6-7?

Comment: A quick search returned no useful results for SCOP. Please expand your abbreviations when they're not common. This site is frequented primarily by laypersons, not industry experts.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely they will get better! Every year company's invent new methods of controll that have increased performance, research is on going to find better forms of "Freon" that are more efficient and don't have a global warming or ozone depletion problems. How fast will it happen? Right now there are small increments of improvement every year and who knows someone may have a groundbreaking discovery that takes us to a whole new level of efficiency. Would I wait to purchase a unit for my home? No I would do it now, well I did do it to my latest home not long ago. The advancements are usually small but continual as each of the big players try to be the best so if you wait 5 years the rating of the best units may improve 1 or 2 seer. 20 years ago 13 was a good value now we are getting above 20- 22 with many mfg's. Note seer is seasonal energy efficiency ratio. The higher the better.  I use that instead of the coefficient of performance since seer is the standard comparison in the trade. To further answer your question we would need to know why you ask.

Comment: What is the best to use currently? R32?

Comment: Currently R410a / r407 are  the leading type that will be around for a while R134a will be phased out sooner from what I have read, R32 has a lower global warming potential, but it is new so it may take some time to get more systems out there, I think daikin has a design on the market but I member reading there may still need to be improvements in the design so it may not be wise to purchase a system until the next generation of designs. I am recommending r410 because of current cost / efficiencys but just like R12,& R22 are gone or going away in the next 5-6 years so will R410 , 407 & R134.

Comment: R32 is in widespread use down under. Daikin, Hitachi, Fujitsu, Mitsubishi Electric, and I think others have systems being installed now. Mostly in smaller systems though; under 10kW (3ton) capacity.